# Can this set be open in a topological vector space?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological vector space, where the topology (as in Rudin's *Functional Analysis*) is such that,

- every singleton is a closed set,
- the vector space operations are continuous.

Now consider the set $S \subset X$ with the following property.

- $0 \in S$,
- for a nonzero $v \in X$ and all $0 < t < a \in \mathbb R$, we have $tv \notin S$.

Can $S$ be open ? some may argue that the open ball $B_r(0)$, an open beighborhood, intersects $tv$ and so $0$ is not an interior point of $S$ and therefore $S$ can't be open. But that is cheating, since there may be no metric or norm on the space to tell what is an open ball, I know that $0$ looks like a boundary point but how to show that for a vector topology. If my reasoning is wrong somewhere, please hint!

---

**Added:** If am I allowed to take the discrete topology, which doesn't seem to be inconsistant with the vector topology above, then perhaps $S$ is open, but only if the field of scalars has this (discrete) topology too, otherwise, e.g. for $\mathbb R$, it is not going to be the case.

Correct me if I'm wrong

---

**Added:** What are the further conditions on the vector topology such that $S$ is open, if we exclude the (trivial) discrete topology ?

Comment: It is clear that $a$ is positive, since it *greater* than $t$ which is *greater* than $0$. I don't know what else this $0 < t < a$ can mean

Comment: $S$ depends on the undeclared variable $a$.  Each choice of $a$ gives a different $S$.  Which $a$ is intended or is it intended that we resolve the openness of $S(a)$ for all (positive real) choices of $a$?

Comment: If $S$ can be be open for some *positive* $a$ I'll be glad to know for which one, and how

Comment: If $X$ is nontrivial (that is, is not zero dimensional) and you are in the usual setting with real or complex scalars having their standard topology, then the discrete topology is disallowed because the discrete metric fails to make scalar multiplication continuous.  Of course, if you have a finite field of scalars, this is no longer a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $S\subseteq X$ is open with $0\in S$. The map $\mu\colon \Bbb R\times X\to X$, $(c,w)\mapsto cw$ is continuous. The set  $\mu^{-1}(S)$ is open and hence of the form
$$\mu^{-1}(S)=\bigcup_{i\in I}\left]a_i,b_i\right[\times V_i$$
with real $a_i,b_i$ and open $V_i\subset X$. From $(0,v)\in\mu^{-1}(S)$, we see that there must exist some $i\in I$ with $a_i<0<b_i$ and $v\in V_i$. Pick $t\in\left]0,\min\{b_i,a\}\right[$. Then $tv\in S$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $v$ be as in the second assumption about $S$. By continuity of the vector space operations, the function $f:\mathbb R\to X:t\mapsto tv$ is continuous. If $S$ were open then, since it contains $0=f(0)$, it would have to contain $f(t)$ for all $t$ sufficiently near $0$ in $\mathbb R$. That contradicts our choice of $v$, so $S$ is not open.